# accessing arrays in json object without using keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a `JSON` object of arrays

```
data = {
   China: ["Guangzhou","Fax"],
   Majorette: ["Fungous","Godzilla"],
   Bhutan: ["Thimphu","Parr","Photofinishing"]
}
```

I want to access name of cities in an array without explicitly mentioning the name of countries as list is very long.

```
var cities = [];
for(var i in data.China) {
   cities[i] = data.China[i];
}
```

How should I do for all the countries?

Comment: You want to flatten the array of cities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should populate the cities array:

```
var data = {
China: ["Guangzhou","Fax"],
Majorette: ["Fungous","Godzilla"],
Bhutan: ["Thimphu","Parr","Photofinishing"]
}

var cities = [];
for(var i in data){
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        for(var j in data[i] ){
             if(data[i].hasOwnProperty(j)){
                cities.push(data[i][j]);
             }
        }
    }

}

console.log(cities);
```

[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L3txz2r2/2/)

Comment: Note that you can use `[]` in place of `new Array` and that a loop that pushes things is just a `array.map`.

Comment: Good, now note that some browsers like IE8 don't have a notion of enmerable and non-enumerable properties so when you iterate an array with a for... in you'll get an extra key for the `.length` for example. This means you should wrap that code in a hasOwnProperty check. See http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: good findings @BenjaminGruenbaum. Learned something. updated.

Comment: Great, I've removed my downvote. Now - please consider that iterating arrays with `for... in` loops is considered bad practice since the iteration order is not guaranteed. To be fair OP did not ask for it here so it's not a huge deal but using [`data[i].forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or even better [`data[i].map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) could make your core shorter and potentially more correct.

Comment: If you modify your code to not nest 5 levels and explain why it's written this way (vs your original revision) I'll gladly upvote this answer.

Comment: Thanks Riad, Code is giving the required result.

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over the cities object effectively:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    // In here, data[key] is each array of cities.
});
```

Now, from what I understand from your question, you want to reduce the multidimensional object/array to one flat array of cities:

```
var cities = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(arr, key) {
    return arr.concat(data[key]);
}, []);
```

Please note that `Object.keys`, as well as `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.reduce` are IE9 and above functions.

Comment: @PraffulGupta You're welcome. Note that you can accept the answer (and thus marking it as "complete") that solved your problem by click on the large tick mark below the question's score. Only use it if the answer really solved your problem though.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var key in data) {
    var citiesArray = data[key]; // cities for the current country
    // your code

}
```

Comment: @SecondRikudo I'm pretty sure `.length` is not enumerable. That said it will count it in old browsers like IE8

Answer (score -1):

```
 for (var country in data){
    for(var i=0;i<data[country].length;i++){
        console.log (data[country][i]);   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, it will print all the cities to console, but it should also have following code to append the cities.
cities.push(data[country][i]);